# javascript include by src works on live server but not on localhost

Tags: javascript, localhost, include, live

I use
`<script src="./js/common.js"></script>` to include common.js file in the header of HTML file which is test.html.
only a test function in the common.js:

```
function test(){
console.log('test')}
```

I run test() function on test.html and found that when I use live server to open the test.html,it works well on URL below:
http://127.0.0.1:5500/test/test.html
but if I open the same test.html by http://localhost:8081/test.html , it shows "Uncaught ReferenceError: test is not defined".

Could someone tell me why?
thanks!

I have no idea why function definition missed in the included file.